# apply() function not working on individual rows

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, apply

I have written a function to extract data from a large matrix ("c.mat") for each row in a data.frame ("df.1"). The data.frame has an indexing row in it ("df.1$hour") which corresponds to the relevant column in the matrix. There is an equal number of rows between the matrix and the data.frame so the function goes:

```
assignUV.FUN <- function(df, mat){
  num=df$hour
  value = mat[as.numeric(rownames(df)),num]
  return(value)
}
```

Quite simple. However when using apply to run this for each row:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(hour= round(runif(10,1,100)), x = seq(1,10, length=10))
c.mat <- matrix(runif(1000,1,5), nrow=10)

try <- apply(df.1, 1, assignUV.FUN, mat = c.mat, df=df.1)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (newX[, i])
```

I'm sure there is a conflict here whereby I am calling the data.frame twice, once from inside the `assignUV.FUN` function and once with `apply` but I can;t figure out why this won't work.

Any thoughts? It works fine if I just run on a single row:

```
assignUV.FUN(df = df.1[1,], mat=c.mat)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to subset `c.mat` for every row in `df.1` based on value in `hour` column. I don't think `apply` is the best choice here since you want to subset it by both row and column index. `apply` passes the value of the row and not it's index which you need for subsetting.  One option from the `apply` family is to use `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x, y) c.mat[x, y], seq_len(nrow(df.1)), df.1$hour)
#[1] 2.472 3.980 3.654 4.868 4.204 3.320 4.191 3.296 1.016 4.353
```

Or a vectorised approach would be

```
c.mat[cbind(1:nrow(df.1), df.1$hour)]
#[1] 2.472 3.980 3.654 4.868 4.204 3.320 4.191 3.296 1.016 4.353
```

---

To get into details of why it works when you apply for one row individually and not when you use `apply` notice when you subset one row it is still a one row dataframe with header.

```
df.1[1, ]
#  hour x
#1   31 1

class(df.1[1, ])
#[1] "data.frame"
```

So when you do `df$hour` in the `assignUV.FUN` function you will get a value

```
df.1[1, ]$hour
#[1] 31
```

However, that is not the case with `apply`

```
apply(df.1[1, ], 1, class)
#        1 
#"numeric"
```

and if you try to extract the value

```
apply(df.1[1, ], 1, function(x) x$hour)
```

> Error in x$hour : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

You can solve the above issue by using position instead of name by doing

```
apply(df.1[1, ], 1, function(x) x[1])
#31
```

but this gives you column to subset from `c.mat` and not the row.

**data**

```
set.seed(100)
df.1 <- data.frame(hour= round(runif(10,1,100)), x = seq(1,10, length=10))
c.mat <- matrix(runif(1000,1,5), nrow=10)
```

Comment: You have understood, and this has answered the query perfectly, thank you. I see why apply was inappropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Ronak's vector approach is the way to go, but I hope this can be instructive. `apply` does not pass a `data.frame` to `FUN`, but instead a vector, so you can try,

```
assignUV.FUN <- function(DF, mat){
  num=DF[1]
  value = mat[DF[2],num]
  return(value)
}

try <- apply(df.1, 1, assignUV.FUN, mat = c.mat)
```

It is unnecessary to pass all arguments of `FUN` to `apply`, I only passed `c.mat` since it is not being 'looped through'. Also, I try to avoid naming `data.frame`s `df`, since `R` already has a function called `df` (density of the F distribution).

Comment: Thank you Simon, this is very helpful to understanding the use of apply appropriately. Makes sense that apply would pass a vector rather than a data.frame given the errors I was getting. I also never would call my data frame df however this was just for a reproducible example.